# PHP non txt files wont open when downloaded

Tags: php, file, pdo

On my website i allow a user to download a biography someone else posted while filling out a form. The problem I am recieving is that when I open a downloaded "txt" file, it opens fine but, when its like "docx or accdb" file, I get error messages like

```
We're sorry. We can't open xxx because we found a problem with its contents.
Details>>
The file is corrupt and cannot be opened
```

and I believe the problem happens when I get the file from the user. Here is my code

Upload file

```
$bio_name = $_FILES['biography']['name'];
 $bio_tmp = $_FILES['biography']['tmp_name'];
 $bio_size = $_FILES['biography']['size'];
 $bio_type = $_FILES['biography']['type'];
 $ext = pathinfo($bio_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


                if($ext=="pdf"||$ext=="PDF"||$ext=="doc"||$ext=="DOC"||$ext=="docx"||$ext=="DOCX"
                ||$ext=="XLS"||$ext=="xls"||$ext=="XLSX"||$ext=="xlsx"||$ext=="xlsm"||$ext=="XLSM"){
$fp = fopen($bio_tmp, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($bio_tmp));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);


 }else{


echo "<script>
alert('ERROR: This file format is not supported');
window.location.href='form.php';
</script>";
     }
```

Download file

```
$size = $formData['bio_size'];
        $type = $formData['bio_type'];
        $file = $formData['bio_filename'];
        $content = $formData['bio_tmp'];
         header("Content-length: $size");
         header("Content-type: $type");
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
         ob_clean();
         flush();
         echo $content;
```

Comment: Check the content-type, i am not sure that the file type is the expected content-type in response header.

Comment: Also check the MIME-types of your server. If it's an unrecognized filetype, the server probably won't process it.

Comment: @4EACH I researched it and changed i from"$type" to "application/force-download" and Its the same thing not sure why

Comment: @Michel I have it set to longblob if thats what you're asking me to find